# universal C* algebras

Tags: operator-algebras

Is there a standard reference which has a discussion on universal $C^*$-algebras ?
(definition, properties, examples, etc)
Searching on the internet has led me to tidbits of information but I would like to read the initial papers or some standard references which introduced these ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blackadar's "Operator Algebras : Theory of C* algebras and Von-Neumann Algebras" has a section on universal C* algebras. So does Blackadar's paper on "Shape Theory for C* algebras".

Comment: In both the sources when talking about the set of relations "We could allow the relations in $\mathcal{R}$ to be any kind of relations which could be formulated for operators on a Hilbert space or for elements of a $C^*$-algebra ..." Is $||a|| \ge ||b||$ a valid kind of relation, where $a$, $b$ are members of the generating set ?

Comment: No, I believe the only valid relationships are of the form $\|p(x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n, x_1^{\ast}, x_2^{\ast}, \ldots, x_n^{\ast})\| \leq \alpha$ for some polynomial $p$ with comlex coefficients in $2n$ commuting variables, $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ in the generating set, and $\alpha \geq 0$

Comment: The author says "for specificity" we consider the relations of the form you wrote. I thought the wording was a bit vague and did not rule out possibilities like the one I mentioned. What is the reason for only considering relations of the above form ?

Comment: I quote Blackadar : "The only restriction on the relations is that they must be realizable among operators on a Hilbert space and they must (at least implicitly) place an upper bound on the norm of each generator when realized as an operator." So, I think conditions like $\|a\| \leq \|b\|$ might be permissible, provided the universal C* algebra so constructed has a representation!

Answer (score 4):

A good place to start is with C*-algebras generated by isometries: See Coburn's 1967 [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-73/issue-5/The-C-algebra-generated-by-an-isometry/bams/1183529041.full) for the case of a single isometry. See Cuntz's 1977 [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-57/issue-2/Simple-C-algebras-generated-by-isometries/cmp/1103901288.full) for the case of several isometries whose range projections partition the identity.

An even simpler case is the universal C*-algebra generated by a single unitary which is just $C(\mathbb{T})$, as follows from functional calculus. It is instructive to convince yourself that there does *not* exist, for instance, a universal C*-algebra generated by a single self-adjoint.

Group C*-algebras and, more generally, crossed products constitute important examples of universal C*-algebras. A 1986 [paper](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://journals.cambridge.org/production/action/cjoGetFulltext?fulltextid=2698812&ei=FY4QUoqYCsXuyQHvioCoBg&usg=AFQjCNH5hWiamw6aEBzHfBejPFcu7GYpgQ&sig2=M_1jznHdVEY9kjCLQgNwjA&bvm=bv.50768961,d.aWc) of Ian Raeburn makes the universality of crossed-products precise.

Semigroup crossed products are also popular, see the classical case of Toeplitz algebras. Even more generally, one has graph C*-algebras.

Comment: Interestingly, the universal Cstar algebra generated by a *partial* isometry is apparently quite horrible: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2012-140-01/S0002-9939-2011-10988-2/S0002-9939-2011-10988-2.pdf

Comment: If we work in the category of unital $C^*$-algebras and unital maps, do you know whether it is equally horrible?

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you want to know exactly. There's some relatively elementary (but still useful) information in Davidson's `C$^*$-algebra's by Example' in Chapter 7 on Group C$^*$-algebras. It also goes into the related reduced C$^*$-algebras.

As I say it depends on your interest's I suspect. I had to learn about them for C$^*$-algebraic quantum groups for which Timmerman's book `An Invitation to Quantum Groups and Duality' has various bits of information scattered plus some brief (though again useful) information in the appendix.